# PowerShell escape sequence

Tags: bash, powershell, escaping

I am passing an escape sequence as a parameter of a command in bash using the `$'\035'` or `$'\x1d'` escape sequence.  This is interpreted as an ASCII 29 which is the `Cntl[` character.  The reason I need to use an obscure character is because the data I am building, the CSV file has the standard escape sequences in the data.

Does PowerShell have a comparable way to pass a parameter so it is interpreted as a single character?  I couldn't find anything online.  The PS documentation only lists the standard escape sequences.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
bash$ command -f $'/x1d'
ps$ command -f ???'/x1d'
```

Comment: `[char]29` will make ASCII char 29. Might need () around it.

Comment: This helped.  It turns out you can't insert the '[char]29' directly in the parameter string.  I created a variable '$delimiter = [char]29'  and passed the variable as a parameter.  '[char]0x1d' also works.